Firebase RecyclerView not Displaying Retrieved Data in Fragment Despite Successful Fetch and Adapter Setup In kotlin Xml Android
I'm unable to display data retrieved from the Firebase Realtime Database in a RecyclerView within my Android application.
Despite successfully fetching the data (as confirmed by logging), the RecyclerView remains empty when the fragment is displayed.
I have implemented a RecyclerView adapter (postadapter) with multiple view holders (TextViewHolder, ImageViewHolder, VideoViewHolder, ImageVideoViewHolder) to handle different types of post content (text, images, videos).
Adapter Debug Logs: Despite initializing the adapter and logging from within the adapter (Log.d statements), no logs are appearing in Logcat, suggesting potential issues with how the RecyclerView or adapter is being updated or rendered.
UI Rendering: The RecyclerView remains visually empty despite data being available and correctly fetched from Firebase.
I have implemented a RecyclerView adapter (communitypostadapter) with multiple view holders (TextViewHolder, ImageViewHolder, VideoViewHolder, ImageVideoViewHolder) to handle different types of post content (text, images, and videos) and  I've implemented a RecyclerView inside Fragment which is actually for Tabs and The Toast inside Fragment is showing so that Means Fragment is initialized but retrieving values from firebase and display it in RecylerView won't work. from the Log I got to understand retrieving values is working. I'm unable to understand what's the problem. I will provide relevant code and database structure.
PostFragment :
class postscommunityfragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_postscommunityfragment, container, false)

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_posts)

        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        postList = mutableListOf()

        val name = arguments?.getString("name")
        Toast.makeText(context, name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        val userId = user?.uid

        databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("CommunityPosts").child(name!!).child(userId!!)

        databaseRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                postList.clear()
                for (postSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                    val post = postSnapshot.getValue(postdataclass::class.java)
                    post?.let { postList.add(it) }
                }
                // Initialize adapter and set it after fetching posts
                postAdapter = communitypostadapter(requireContext(), postList)
                recyclerView.adapter = postAdapter
                Log.d("postscommunityfragment", "Fetched ${postList.size} posts")
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Log.e("postscommunityfragment", "Database error: ${error.message}")
            }
        })
    }
}


Post Adapter :

class postadapter(private val context: Context, private val postList: List<postdataclass>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    companion object {
        private const val TYPE_TEXT_ONLY = 0
        private const val TYPE_TEXT_IMAGE = 1
        private const val TYPE_TEXT_VIDEO = 2
        private const val TYPE_TEXT_IMAGE_VIDEO = 3
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        val post = postList[position]
        Log.d("communitypostadapter", "getItemViewType for position $position")
        return when {
            post.imguri != null && post.videouri != null -> TYPE_TEXT_IMAGE_VIDEO
            post.imguri != null -> TYPE_TEXT_IMAGE
            post.videouri != null -> TYPE_TEXT_VIDEO
            else -> TYPE_TEXT_ONLY
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        Log.d("communitypostadapter", "onCreateViewHolder for viewType $viewType")
        return when (viewType) {
            TYPE_TEXT_IMAGE -> ImageViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.communitypostimageitem, parent, false))
            TYPE_TEXT_VIDEO -> VideoViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.communitypostvideoitem, parent, false))
            TYPE_TEXT_IMAGE_VIDEO -> ImageVideoViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.communitypostvideoimageitem, parent, false))
            else -> TextViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.communityposttextitem, parent, false))
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val post = postList[position]
        Log.d("communitypostadapter", "onBindViewHolder for position $position")
        when (holder) {
            is TextViewHolder -> holder.bind(post)
            is ImageViewHolder -> holder.bind(post)
            is VideoViewHolder -> holder.bind(post)
            is ImageVideoViewHolder -> holder.bind(post)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return postList.size
    }

    inner class TextViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val postText: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_post)
        private val username: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_username)

        fun bind(post: postdataclass) {
            Log.d("TextViewHolder", "bind post: ${post.post}")
            postText.text = post.post
            username.text = post.username
        }
    }

    inner class ImageViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val postText: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_post)
        private val username: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_username)
        private val postImage: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_post)

        fun bind(post: postdataclass) {
            Log.d("ImageViewHolder", "bind post: ${post.post}")
            postText.text = post.post
          
        }
    }

    //Also did created another two viewholder for videos and images
}


and Logs which are inside of Adapter Did not displayed and i created four viewholder as post can contain post text only or post text with many images or post text with many videos or post text with videos and images so that's why i did created four viewholders and i dont know where is the issue inside fragment or adapter ? and i also tried send custom values to adapter if its working but it didnt worked.
I will also provide my Firebase Database structure :
{
  "CommunityPosts": {
    "name": {
      "ve7UmHpwqsuMeORHkKTffWWViZ8zd2": {
        "-O-_1nzOQs0hf7S5EOEw": {
          "currenttime": "currentimr",
          "post": "postdetails",
          "userimg": "uimgurl",
          "username": "username"
        },
        "-O-_2ES4itNTsmGccBye": {
          "currenttime": "currentime",
          "imguri": [
            "urls"
          ],
          "post": "post",
          "userimg": "uimgurl",
          "username": "username"
        },
        "-O-_2POg6ludb1x996FE": {
          "currenttime": "currenttime",
          "post": "post",
          "userimg": "userimg",
          "username": "username",
          "videouri": [
            "urls"
          ]
        },
        "-O-_2_URXwNDghuKoPrJ": {
          "currenttime": "currentime",
          "imguri": [
            "urls"
          ],
          "post": "post",
          "userimg": "",
          "username": "username",
          "videouri": [
            "urls"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


I Added Structure so that it can help to understand my code. I dont know where and what's the issue.
DATACLASS:
data class postdataclass(
    val post: String? = null,
    val imguri: List<String>? = null,
    val videouri: List<String>? = null,
    val username: String? = null,
    val userimg: String? = null,
    val currenttime: String? = null
)

Can we Use RecylerView Inside Fragment ? and From Logs I can Understand Adapter it didnt called so it still confuses me.

You have a log.d and  log.e inside the addValueEventListener callbacks. Does either of these write to you your logcag?

in above code i can see differnet name when you intialize adapter and what is actua adapter class name , maybe it could be reason that you facing this issue

@FrankvanPuffelen yes that log.d is displays that "Fetched 4 items" actually which is correct but It didn't displayed items in RecylerView

@KevinKalathiya Actually I changed that when Posting on Stack Overflow, so I think That's not a problem

I recommend doing some local debugging to see what happens with the data. Set a breakpoint on the first line of code inside onDataChange, run in the debugger until that hits, and then step through the code - checking the value of each variable on each line until you find one that doesn't match your expectations.

That Log is working it displayed : 4 items fetched , I think Problem is related to view related or something that i dont know and Thanks for your following up

As far as I can see the problem in your code lies in the following line of code:
databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").child(name!!).child(userId!!)
//                                                          

Where you call .getReference("Posts") and not .getReference("CommunityPosts") as it exists in the database. The name of the node that is passed to the getReference() method should match the name of the node in the database.

Actually, you are right. However, when posting on Stack Overflow, I changed it to "Posts". Before that, it was "CommunityPosts", which I did to reduce the number of words and also in Log I can Get Size of posts from firebase so that is working i think

Hey there. So did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

unfortunately, no sir Because I think That's not a problem even though I changed it doesn't work.

"it doesn't work" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?

Thanks for following up. Unfortunately, the change didn't resolve the issue. Even though I changed "Posts" to "CommunityPosts," it still doesn't work as expected. Here's what I'm encountering:
Items are not displayed in RecyclerView even though Firebase is able to fetch values.
Logs in the Adapter are not being displayed.
I am not a native English speaker, so I apologize for any mistakes in my writing. Thank you for your understanding.
